# Заполнение массива циклом + Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, циклы

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    ids = [1, 5, 20484011]; //список с айдишниками
    names = []; //массив для записи имён

    function print_name() {

      $.each(ids, function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=' + this + '&v=5.63', //перебирая массив, получаем информацию о страницах, соответствующих указанному id
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          success: function(result) {

            names.push(result.response[0].last_name); //добавляем в массив фамилию

          }
        });


      });
      console.log(names); //выводим результат
    }
  </script>

  <button onclick='print_name()'>Click</button>
</body>

</html>
```

В данном коде мы делаем несколько GET-запросов, результат которых записываем в список 'names'. Но проблема в том, что если после этого захотим просмотреть полученный результат, то выведет пустой массив и лишь при повторном вызове функции он заполнится. Как всё это дело можно поправить?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что вы пытались выводить результаты в консоль еще до того как получили ответ от сервера, так как методы ajax работают асинхронно они имеют callback-функции, вы используете функцию success которая срабатывает когда получен ответ от сервера, в ней же вам и необходимо выводить результат.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <script>
    ids = [1, 5, 20484011]; //список с айдишниками
    names = []; //массив для записи имён

    function print_name() {
      $.each(ids, function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=' + this + '&v=5.63', //перебирая массив, получаем информацию о страницах, соответствующих указанному id
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          success: function(result) {
            names.push(result.response[0].last_name); //добавляем в массив фамилию
            console.log(names); //выводим результат
          }
        });
      });
    }
  </script>
  <button onclick='print_name()'>Click</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, до это я дошел)
Но если нужно, чтобы метод вызывался после окончательного заполнения массива, а каждую итерацию, юзать $.ajax вообще не вариант и лучше использовать тот же XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: есть, например, вариант вызвать  console.log только при последней итерации цикла.